# Serialize custom Line class

Tags: c#, serialization

I look for a means of serialize a `List<Line>`.

For a `List<string>` or `List<int>` I use :

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
     XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
     xml.Serialize(fs, this.ListCo);
}
```

But that does not work with a `List<Line>`. How i can save this list ?

I forgot to put the error message :
Une erreur s'est produite lors de la réflexion du type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Windows.Shapes.Line]'.

The class "Line" is  public sealed class Line : Shape

Maybe this class is not serializable ?

Comment: whats a `line` and what does "does not work" entail? errors? exceptions?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the Line type? Is it your custom class Line? Or is it WPF Line? Or something else?

Comment: I think I see an error in your code: you tell us you must serialize a `List<Line>` but you try to serialize it as `List<int>`

Comment: @Marco I think it works with `List<int>` but fails with `List<Line>` and he is looking for a solution for the last

Comment: can you post the definition of your `Line` class? According to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx it does not neccessary depend on `Serializable ` or any other attribute/interface and yes @Marco is insofar right, that the part with `List<int>` would be wrong

Comment: @Sayse the error is : Une erreur s'est produite lors de la réflexion du type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Windows.Shapes.Line]'.

Comment: @Marco it works List<int> i looking for a solution for the list<Line>

Comment: Of course those classes are not serializable (they inherit DispatcherObject - so they have a context that is NOT serializable) - and you should not serialize UI elements! - Extrakt the points into your own representation and serialialize these

Answer (score 1):

Yuor class " `Line` " must be `Serializable` :

```
[Serializable()]
    public class Line
    { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think this is really neccessary - I just tested it and **NO** you don't need it - it will serilialize pocos just fine

Answer (score 1):

I think I see an error in your code: you tell us you must serialize a `List<Line>` but you try to serialize it as `List<int>`...

Anyway I want to provide a piece of codeI use to serialize a generic class:

```
class Xml
{
    public static string Serialize(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(mem, objectToSerialize);
        var ascii = new UTF8Encoding();
        return ascii.GetString(mem.ToArray());
    }
    public static string ToFile(object objectToSerialize, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            var s = Serialize(objectToSerialize);
            File.WriteAllText(filename, s);
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So, having a class called obj, I can write `var xml = obj.Serialize();` or `obj.ToFile(filename);`

To serialize a class, it must be serializable and public; class properties will be persisted only if they are public and have accessors!

Comment: @CarstenKönig: well, I think he can use whatever he wants to serialize a class into xml: my extensions do exactly that! More: look at his code, it's buggy (as suggested in my comment and in my answer).
Anyway, I think my answer addresses his problem... maybe not :D

Comment: @CarstenKönig: my answer uses `XmlSerializer`... did you take a look at it? :P

Comment: I tested the code a bit and yes your comment might be the right one (hard to tell while not seeing his class) - it will throw an exception if the type is wrong

Comment: Maybe you should put this part on top of your answer and give the a subheading

Comment: I forgot to put the error message :
Une erreur s'est produite lors de la réflexion du type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Windows.Shapes.Line]'.

The class "Line" is  public sealed class Line : Shape

Maybe this class is not serializable ?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: changed the answer accordingly to your input, thanks :)